# What's the right way to write custom checks for SonarQube 4.5

Tags: sonarqube

What is currently the best way to write SonarQube 4.5 checks for :

1. Bytecode Analysis
2. Source Analysis

Unfortunately, I could not find an up-to-date web page providing a clear explanation, and I see that existing checks use many deprecated classes and methods, use "bridges" about to be abandonned, checks are regularly removed from the codebase (such as the XPath rule).

I would like to be sure that the checks I'm about to write will be well written and durable.

So...

- should I use `BytecodeVisitor` to analyse bytecode ?
- should I use `BaseTreeVisitor` to analyse sourcecode ?
- What is the replacement for `org.sonar.api.rules.RuleRepository` ?
- What is the replacement for `org.sonar.api.resources.Java` ?
- What is the replacement for `org.sonar.api.rules.AnnotationRuleParser` ?
- How can I write XPath like rules (`BaseTreeVisitor` is using SSLR and if I'm not wrong SonarQube is moving away from SSLR / `AbstractXPathCheck` is part of sslr squid bridge.)
- What else should I know ?

In other words I'm a bit lost.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I tend to think that stackoverflow is not the best place for such question and you should ask them on the mailing list which will be more suited for such discussions.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks for your feedback, 
There are in fact many questions in your question (sic) :

The way to write custom checks for Java as of today is to use the `BaseTreeVisitor`. All the other ways are now deprecated and we are working to be able to remove them (but it is not always straightforward as some of them requires a complete semantic analysis to be removed). What is currently lacking from this api is the access to the semantic analysis to be able to request type information read from bytecode.
You can have a look at this project : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules

For all the other questions, please ask them on the mailing list.

(Small notes though : BaseTreeVisitor does not use SSLR directly, the java plugin is not moving away from SSLR rather from one class, specifically `ASTNode`, in order to work on a SyntaxTree with a class specific for each type of node, The drop of Xpath checks occurs in that logic of moving away from a non-typed SyntaxTree).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does not completely answer the question. I already read the example page you're referring to, unfortunately, it's not written for SonarQube 4.5, but for 4.1. Among other things it uses ``RulesRepository`` which is deprecated since 4.3 and is supposed to be replaced by ``RulesDefinition`` but no information is provided about the impact (if any) of this modification.

Comment: To be honnest, more or less the same question about RuleDefinition usage was asked on the mailing list mid-june, and until now no clear answer was provided about how to bind checks to rules : http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/sonar-dev-What-s-the-replacement-of-former-AnnotationRuleParser-in-Plugin-API-td5025784.html